# atomのtreeviewでファイル名でファイルを選択する方法

Tags: atom-editor

atomで、ツリービューにプロジェクトのファイルがたくさん表示されているときに、hjklによる1行1行のファイルの移動ではなく、例えばtemplatesというディレクトリがあったときに、tとタイプするだけで、ファイル名やディレクトリ名にtが含まれるものだけ上から順番に選択できるようなプラグイン、もしくは設定がありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

fuzzy-finderパッケージ（デフォルトで入ってる)ではどうでしょうか。以下のコマンドのあとにファイル名を入力していくとプロジェクトフォルダーからファイルが絞られていきます。
Mac: <kbd>cmd+p</kbd> または <kbd>cmd+t</kbd>
Win: <kbd>ctrl+p</kbd> または <kbd>ctrl+t</kbd>

Comment: ありがとうございます！advanced-open-fileというパッケージで、少し意図していた動きとは違いますが対応できました。

Comment: @joe-ro もしお時間があれば、今後同じ問題にあたった人のためにコメントの内容を回答にしてベストアンサーにお選び頂けますか（自分の質問に自分で回答してもいいサイトなので）。

Answer (score 2):

自己解決ですが、今後同じ問題にあたった人のために投稿します。
advanced-open-fileというパッケージで、少し意図していた動きとは違いますが対応でき‌​ました。